# pytest/pylint in conda environment

Tags: python, anaconda, pytest, conda

I know how to run a pytest and pylint in python using a requirements.txt file (containing pytest and pylint):

```
python -m venv .
.\scripts\activate
pip install -r requirements.txt
pytest <filename>
```

However I'm not sure on how to do this on conda, so far I have:

```
conda create --name testenv --file requirements.txt
conda activate testenv
??
```

I'm not sure what to put next in order to run a pylint or pytest.
I've taken a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34445171/pylint-failing-in-conda-environment) which uses `pylint filename.py` after.
Or [would](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/pytest) `conda install -c anaconda pylint` and then `pylint <filename.py>`?

I assume it would be similar steps for pytest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The process in general is the same - or it might be more precise to say it's analogous. Conda is not an analogous tool in all respects, but for this, the steps should look familiar.

```
# create your virtual environment
conda create --name testenv
# activate your virtual environment
conda activate testenv
# install your tools
conda install pytest pylint -c conda-forge --yes
# run your tools
pytest path/to/tests/
pylint path/to/files/
```

I'm not sure what "in multiple directories" in your title refers to.